# Winforms N-Tier - Retrieve and display image from sql server database

Tags: sql-server, image, winforms, n-tier-architecture

Am new to N-Tier programming and in the process of learning more, I want to retrieve an image from SQL Server database using N-tier architecture. I have managed to save the image but am facing issues in getting the image from the database, passing it as a parameter and then displaying the image.

Data Access Layer Code:

```
Public Function SelectRecord(ByVal clsdbo_ProductsPara As AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_Products) As AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_Products
    Dim clsDAL_Products As New AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_Products
    Dim connTemp As SqlConnection = AppName.DataAccess.AppNameDataClass.GetConnection
    Dim strSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID"
    Dim cmdSelect As New SqlCommand(strSelect, connTemp)
    cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", clsdbo_ProductsPara.ProductID)
    Try
        connTemp.Open()
        Dim rdrTemp As SqlDataReader = strCommandSelect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
        If rdrTemp.Read Then
            With clsdbo_ProductsPara
                .ProductID = System.Convert.ToString(rdrTemp("ProductID"))
                .ProductDesc = If(IsDBNull(rdrTemp("ProductDesc")), Nothing, rdrTemp("ProductDesc"))
                .ProductImage = If(IsDBNull(rdrTemp("ProductImage")), Nothing, rdrTemp("ProductImage"))
            End With
        Else
            clsdbo_ProductsPara = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Finally
        connTemp.Close()
    End Try
    Return clsdbo_ProductsPara
End Function
```

Presentation Layer Code:

```
Private Sub DisplaySelectedRecordDetails()
    Dim clsdbo_ProductsPara As New AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_Products
    clsdbo_ProductsPara.ProductID = System.Convert.ToString(lblProductID.Text)
    clsdbo_ProductsPara = clsdbo_ProductsData.SelectRecord(clsdbo_ProductsPara)
    If Not clsdbo_ProductsPara Is Nothing Then
        Try
            txtProductDesc.Text = Convert.ToString(clsdbo_ProductsPara.ProductDesc)
            picProductImage.Image = Nothing
            If Not IsDBNull(clsdbo_ProductsPara.ProductImage) Then
                Dim data As Byte = Convert.ToByte(clsdbo_ProductsPara.ProductImage.GetType)
                Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(New MemoryStream)
                bw.Write(clsdbo_ProductsPara.ProductImage)
                Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(bw.BaseStream, True)
                Me.picProductImage.Image = img
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

First, I had like to know what is the correct way of retrieving the image using this method. Secondly I am getting conversion errors Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'Byte' is not valid. in the DAL block on the line  .ProductImage = If(IsDBNull(rdrTemp("ProductImage")), Nothing, rdrTemp("ProductImage"))

Please help correct the above for me to understand.

Thanks

CL

Comment: please provide details of your conversion errors

Comment: Hi Tanner, I know there are many mistakes and errors in the code above. The error I am getting is -- Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'Byte' is not valid. in the line---.ProductImage = If(IsDBNull(rdrTemp("ProductImage")), Nothing, rdrTemp("ProductImage"))

Comment: Add the error to your question where you mention the conversion error, it's easier for people to read that way.